# c++ mcrypt error at mcrypt_generic

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mcrypt

I have the following code:

[test.cpp]

```
#include <mcrypt.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char algo[] = "rijndael-256";
  char mode[] = "cbc";
   char *block_buffer=(char*)"HELLO!! MY NAME IS: ";
cout<<"here"<<endl;
string s;
char key="1234-5678-9654-7512-7895-2543-12";


  char iv[]  = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};;

  MCRYPT td = mcrypt_module_open(algo, NULL, mode, NULL);
  if (td == MCRYPT_FAILED) { cout<<"error"<<endl;}

int keysize=32;
  int r =  mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, keysize, iv);
if (r<0)
{
    cout<<"error2"<<endl;
    mcrypt_perror(r);
            return 1;

}

 //while ( fread (&block_buffer, 1, 1, stdin) == 1 ) {
   int j=          mcrypt_generic (td, &block_buffer, sizeof(block_buffer));
if (j!=0){std::cout<<"error encrypting"<<std::endl;} // I HAVE ERROR HERE J==0


 //how to print the encrypted string??

 cout<<"buffer "<<block_buffer<<endl; //this is not the encriperd string. why?

    mcrypt_generic_deinit(td);

  mcrypt_module_close(td);
}
```

I am testing the code:

```
$: g++ test.cpp -o tst -lmcrypt  
                      $: ./tst
```

WHERE SHOULT I ADD THE `PKCS 7?`

I have the following method:

```
std::string add_pkcs7_padding(std::string s, std::size_t n)
{
  const std::size_t fill = n - (s.length() % n);
  s.append(fill, static_cast<char>(fill));
  return s;
}

std::string strip_pkcs7_padding(std::string s, std::size_t n)
{
  const std::size_t pad = static_cast<unsigned char>(*s.rbegin());
  return s.substr(0, s.length() - pad);
}
```

I din't know when should i run it and where in my code.

NEED SOME HELP. APPRECIATE A LOT!!

EDIT:

I have error at:  mcrypt_generic (td, &block_buffer, sizeof(block_buffer)); The compiler prints
that the value j=0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke `mcrypt_generic()` with a `char*`, not a `char**` as you do:

```
mcrypt_generic(td, block_buffer, sizeof(block_buffer));
                   ^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                      ouch!
```

Also, the length is wrong, as `sizeof(block_buffer)` is just be the size of the pointer, not the string; if anything you need `strlen(block_buffer)`.

But this is still going to be wrong in general because you need your message to be a multiple of the block size. Use the padding function:

```
std::string s = add_pkcs7_padding(block_buffer, mcrypt_enc_get_block_size(td));
std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());  // this will hold the encrypted data
mcrypt_generic(td, v.data(), v.size());
```

By the way, your plaintext should be declared like this:

```
const char * block_buffer = "HELLO!! MY NAME IS: ";
^^^^^                       ^^^^
  constness!                  no explicit cast!
```

But why so clumsy, it's better to just use a string:

```
std::string plaintext = "HELLO!! MY NAME IS: ";
```

I think you might benefit from picking up a good C++ book and familiarizing yourself with the basics of the language a bit - it's good to have a project to work on, but most of your problems aren't really related to encryption or mcrypt, but just general C++ programming.

Comment: can you please tell me where is the encription added? in the block_buffer? What should  I do if i want to print the encrypted text? Need some help. THX ALOT!! Could you write the code?

Comment: Please, and seriously, *read the manual*. It's all in there. `mcrypt_generic` encrypts the data in place, so the data buffer you pass into it will contain the cipher text after the encryption. Note how I'm using a `vector<char>` to hold the mutable data, since you cannot modify a `string` directly.

Comment: add_pkcs7_padding - method has two arguments. you put just one argumet, what is the second argument?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot - it's the block size (as you may have guessed by looking at the code). I'll edit it.

Comment: i know he result it's printed in a while. the problem is that in my case when i compile..there is nothing printed ..i have a blank page . the program remains in the while and does not print anything. i don't know what to do

Comment: Sorry, another typo - `v` is the vector. I copy the string into a vector so the data can be modified, because you cannot modify the string data directly through a C interface.

Comment: now i have the error:  cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int mcrypt_generic(CRYPT_STREAM*, void*, int)’. REALLY APPRECIATE!!

Comment: mcrypt_generic - has just 3 arguments not four!

Comment: thx:).. i succeded to print the encrypted text. I still do have a proble. I've tested the same plaintext with crypto++. The results are not the same. Plus every time i compile this code the result is different. :( The correct result is the one testes with libcrypto++. I am going to ask this in another question. If you see error let me know. thx